# PyQt widget keeps increasing in size and goes out the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I have written an application in PyQt5. I am basically displaying a camera feed (in this case my web cam), but the problem is that the frame size keeps on increasing at run time and ultimately goes out of my laptop screen. I'm unable to figure out what the problem is.

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Below is the code snippet.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
import cv2
import imutils


class CameraWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """Independent camera feed
    Uses threading to grab IP camera frames in the background

    @param width - Width of the video frame
    @param height - Height of the video frame
    @param stream_link - IP/RTSP/Webcam link
    @param aspect_ratio - Whether to maintain frame aspect ratio or force into fraame
    """

    def __init__(self, width=0, height=0, aspect_ratio=False, parent=None, deque_size=1):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialize deque used to store frames read from the stream
        self.deque = deque(maxlen=deque_size)
        
        self.maintain_aspect_ratio = aspect_ratio
        self.camera_stream_link = 0

        # Flag to check if camera is valid/working
        self.online = False
        self.capture = None

        self.video_frame = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        self.load_network_stream()

        # Start background frame grabbing
        self.get_frame_thread = Thread(target=self.get_frame, args=())
        self.get_frame_thread.daemon = True
        self.get_frame_thread.start()

        # Periodically set video frame to display
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.set_frame)
        self.timer.start(.5)

        print('Started camera: {}'.format(self.camera_stream_link))

    def load_network_stream(self):
        """Verifies stream link and open new stream if valid"""

        def load_network_stream_thread():
            if self.verify_network_stream(self.camera_stream_link):
                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_stream_link)
                self.online = True
        self.load_stream_thread = Thread(target=load_network_stream_thread, args=())
        self.load_stream_thread.daemon = True
        self.load_stream_thread.start()

    def verify_network_stream(self, link):
        """Attempts to receive a frame from given link"""

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            return False
        cap.release()
        return True

    def get_frame(self):
        # time.sleep(5)
        """Reads frame, resizes, and converts image to pixmap"""

        while True:
            try:
                if self.capture.isOpened() and self.online:
                    # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
                    status, frame = self.capture.read()
                    if status:
                        self.deque.append(frame)
                    else:
                        self.capture.release()
                        self.online = False
                else:
                    # Attempt to reconnect
                    print('attempting to reconnect', self.camera_stream_link)
                    self.load_network_stream()
                    self.spin(2)
                self.spin(.001)
            
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def spin(self, seconds):
        """Pause for set amount of seconds, replaces time.sleep so program doesnt stall"""

        time_end = time.time() + seconds
        while time.time() < time_end:
            QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()

    def set_frame(self):
        """Sets pixmap image to video frame"""

        if not self.online:
            self.spin(1)
            return

        if self.deque and self.online:
            # Grab latest frame
            frame = self.deque[-1]

            # Keep frame aspect ratio
            if self.maintain_aspect_ratio:
                self.frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=self.screen_width)
            # Force resize
            else:
                self.frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
                self.frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = self.frame.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w

            # Convert to pixmap and set to video frame
            self.img = QtGui.QImage(self.frame, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img)
            self.video_frame.setPixmap(self.pix)

    def set_frame_params(self, width, height):
        self.screen_width = width
        self.screen_height = height

    def get_video_frame(self):
        self.video_frame.setScaledContents(True)
        return self.video_frame


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        # Middle frame
        self.mid_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
        self.mid_frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(153, 187, 255)")

        self.camera = CameraWidget()

        # Create camera widgets
        print('Creating Camera Widgets...')
        self.video_frame = self.camera.get_video_frame()

        self.mid_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.mid_layout.addWidget(self.video_frame)
        self.mid_frame.setLayout(self.mid_layout)


        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.mid_frame)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

    def event(self, e):
        if e.type() in (QtCore.QEvent.Show, QtCore.QEvent.Resize):
            print("resize ", self.mid_frame.width(), self.mid_frame.height())
            self.camera.set_frame_params(self.mid_frame.width()-10, self.mid_frame.height()-10)
        return QtWidgets.QMainWindow.event(self, e)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create main application window
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create("Cleanlooks"))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: How does `self.img = QtGui.QImage(self.frame, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)` not crash when `w` and `h` are not defined (when `self.maintain_aspect_ratio is False`)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `self.maintain_aspect_ratio is True` actually. I believe `h, w, ch = self.frame.shape` and the next line can be unindented.

Comment: As [repeatedly](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) [noted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#geometry-prop) in the documentation, changing the size of a widget within a `resizeEvent()` will cause infinite recursion. In your case the timer is continuously adjusting its size, then the resize event is catched, which causes the call to `set_frame_params()`, which, in turn, will increase the size at the next occurrance of the timeout.

Comment: @Guimoute, no it's ```False```. Look more carefully. It's value is explicitly kept False in the constructor parameter.

Comment: @musicamante, Could you please suggest a way so that I can avoid this infinite recursion problem? I really need the size of that frame.

Comment: @deepanshu You set the default value to False. It seems like you want it to be an option, so all I'm saying is that you will get an UnboundLocalError if you set the option to True because some variables are missing.

Comment: @musicamante Are you sure? `set_frame_params` does not resize anything but just sets the values to use after the next QTimer tick so there should be not recursion here.

Comment: @Guimoute, Yes you are right it will give me an error if I set the option to True but that's not a concern at the moment. I don't intend to change it's value to True, I can even remove that part from my code. But at moment I'm concerned about this resizing issue. Just can't figure out how to handle it and also don't want to hard code any values to it.

Comment: @Guimoute pretty sure, if I'm understanding the logic of the code: `get_video_frame()` returns a QLabel, which is added to the main layout, but using `setScaledContents(True)` only allows to the pixmap to *fit* the available space, it will *never* allow to resize the label to a size smaller than the pixmap. Once the window is resized, `event()` sends the new size parameters for the pixmap, which on the next capture will be set to the main layout, causing a new resize event with a bigger size due to the minimum requirements of the label, creating an even bigger pixmap set for the label, etc...